# AdminLTE v2.3.8. Datatable DateTime column sort

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, sorting, datatables, adminlte

Consider this code (I use razor ASP.NET C# but it doesn't really matter).
I'am able to sort all column but the last one is a datetime which is sorted as string.
I just want to know if it is possible to have a sorting datetime column with AdminLTE datatables, with or without (better) adding plugins.

```html
      <div class="table-responsive">
          <table id="tableClienti" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Zona</th>
                      <th>Classe</th>
                      <th>Rag Soc</th>
                      <th>Indirizzo</th>
                      <th>Email/Telefono</th>
                      <th>Contatto</th>
                      <th>Email/Telefono</th>
                      <th>Ultimo Pass.</th>

                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  @{

                      foreach (var r in Model)
                      {
                          <tr>
                              <td>@r.Zona</td>
                              <td>@r.ClasseCliente</td>
                              <td>@r.RagioneSociale</td>
                              <td><b>@r.Citta @r.CAP</b><br /> @r.Indirizzo</td>
                              <td>@r.Email<br /> @r.Telefono</td>
                              <td><b>@r.NomeContatto<br /> @r.CognomeContatto</b></td>
                              <td>@r.EmailContatto<br /> @r.TelefonoContatto</td>
                              <td>@r.DataUltimoPassaggio</td>
                          </tr>
                      }
                  }


              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
```

```js
  $(function () {
        var table = $("#tableClienti").DataTable({
            paging: false,
            "sDom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"><"clear">',
            "scrollX": true,
            "scrollY": "45vh",
            "bSort": true
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stumble upon this question, I solved after having issues using data-order.

[This link](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) shows how data-order works but this comment found on same page was the key for me:

> Its important to notethat the data-* attributes with search() will
>   only work if you use this on every COL!!! You can not mix it like:
>
> < tr>< td>Value1< /td>< /tr> < tr>< td data-search='Value 2
>   XYZ'>Value2< /td>< /tr> It seems the Plugin-Code always check the first
>   row and then use this value for all search operations. Maybe for the
>   future would be very cool if you can mix it ;):
>
> Best Regards Tom

Previously, I tried to add data-order to < td> only if the "DateTime variable" was not null.
Thanks to this comment I set data-order = "DateTime variable".Ticks when "DateTime variable" is not null and data-order = 0 when "DateTime variable" is null.

So, I changed this piece of code

```
<td>@r.DataUltimoPassaggio</td>
```

in this way

```
@{ 
   DateTime data; 
   if (DateTime.TryParse(r.DataUltimoPassaggio.ToString(), out data)) 
   { 
      <td data-order="@(data.Ticks)">@(data.ToString())</td> 
   } 
   else 
   { 
      <td data-order="0"></td> 
   } 
}
```